# Can we train tensorflow.js to get certain part of image?

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, machine-learning, automation, tensorflow.js

My Client has requirement that user will upload image using that image i have to crop some part of image to do that first i have used **tesseract.js** node module but it's not worked so i moved to tensorflow.js to create my own model and train to crop certain part of images. I want to crop below image signature part and photo. So using object detection of tensorflow can we detect signature and get x and y coordinates to crop images.

[image: Image to crop]

if i get coordinates using below code i can crop certain part of images.

```
const sharp = require("sharp");
sharp("./pancard.jpg")
  .resize(500, 300, {
    fit: sharp.fit.fill
  })
  .toFile("./pancard_new.jpg", (err, info) => {
    sharp("./pancard_new.jpg")
      .extract({ left: 35, top: 220, width: 180, height: 28 })
      .toFile("./pancard_new2.jpg", function(err) {});
  });
```

Comment: Are the input images always fixed ( like the example given in the question )? If yes, then we don't need an ML model to do this task. The signature and photo are always at the same position in the image. We can crop them manually.

Comment: No sometimes user upload imaes like this https://new-img.patrika.com/upload/mediafiles/2017/07/06/l_pancard-farzi-1499313521_835x547.jpg

Answer (score 3):

You would need to have a lot of training data if you wanted to train a machine learning model - maybe thousands of examples of cards which are human annotated with the regions you want to detect and labelled. You can then train something like a segmentation model to extract raw pixels that match those classes, or a multi-box classifier which can give you the bounding box (but may not do so well with things at angles).

The easiest way to train your own and output to TensorFlow.js format would be to try Cloud Auto ML Vision which exports built models to TensorFlow.js. See this tutorial for object detection which gives you bounding boxes back: https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/tensorflow-js-tutorial and then click the Node.js code tab of that tutorial to see how to use in JavaScript on the server side instead of Python.

However as others have mentioned, it may be easier to figure out how to find out where the card is, straighten it, and crop it as that may just be a simple computer vision problem vs a machine learning one.

Comment: Hi @jason, You mean to say instead of write code to train data i can use google UI to train data and using that model data i have to write code to get co-ordinates to crop images...is this google edge is paid??

Comment: Hey @Jason i have checked goggle edge is paid tool. Can you please explain little bit about this "You can then train something like a segmentation model to extract raw pixels that match those classes, or a multi-box classifier which can give you the bounding box (but may not do so well with things at angles)". please provide github link or tutorials link if you have any please.

Comment: Link is in the answer above for the cloud auto ml tutorial. Follow that for the multibox example to retrain on your own data. I dont think there is one for object segmentation yet - for that you would have to make your own manually.